# angular - html - font awesome icon being misaligned on the right side of a div

Tags: html, css, angular, font-awesome, angular-content-projection

[image: see the misalignment of the circles on the right]
I have a list of div, each with an icon, some text and another icon (a circle) which must be on the right side. In order to achieve this, I set the `margin-left` property, but of course the margin is calculated based on the text length, rather that on the parent div position. ***So it results in the circles on the right being misaligned.*** I use the *font awesome* icon pack.

What is shown in the image is obtained through a loop which for each iteration generates an `<app-item-icon>` component

```
<app-item-icon>
          <i icon class="fas fa-2x fa-clipboard-list"></i>
          <span class="span-list-item">{{ item.name }}</span>
          <i class="fas fa-circle" [ngClass]="{'is-active': item.is_active, 'is-not-active': !item.is_active}" ></i>
</app-item-icon>
```

The second `<i>` tag has one of the two following css classes thanks to the `ngClass` property. IMHO that's where my issue hides

```
.is-active {
    color: green;
    margin-left: 90vw !important;
}

.is-not-active {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 90vw !important;
}
```

This is the html file for `<app-item-icon>`:

```
<div class="container">
    <ng-content select="[icon]" ></ng-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

I'm using **Angular** framework with **content-projection**. `<ng-content>` directive will be replaced with a `<div>` container on the rendered template. The first `ng-content` catches the first icon on the left, while the second `ng-content` catches the text and the circle icon which causes mi issue.

This is the css for `<app-item-icon>`

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}

:host ::ng-deep *{
    float: left;
}

:host ::ng-deep i {
    padding: 3px 1px;
    margin-right: 6px !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep :not(i) {
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:**

1. `float: right` on the circle icons: has absolutely no effect at all;
2. `position: absolute` on the circles: that actually works, but unexpectedly the icons become vertically not centered, slightly moved upward;
3. `text-align: end` on the container class: no effect;
4. setting `margin-right` instead of the left one on the circles: no effect because, I think, they don't have any element on their right side;

**ABOUT ANGULAR:** I don't know why, but using the browser inspection tool, I've noticed the circle icons have the `::before` pseudo element set. I think this is due to the Angular content-projection. Maybe it will be helpful to find out a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your class .container has `display: flex`. If you include your span in the first `<ng-content>` by adding [icon], you can change your .container class like this :

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    padding: 0;
}
```

The `justify-content: space-between;`  will display each `<ng-content>` on one side, and the text length won't matter.
Normally, you won't need anymore your `margin-left: 90vw !important;` in your `.is-active .is-not-active` classes.

Comment: Thank you. Ok, so circles are correctly aligned on the right side. The problem now is that `span` content (the text) is centered in the middle of the div, while I want it to be on the left near the first icon. Same behavior also if not including the `span` in the first `ng-content`

Comment: A quick fix can be setting a `width` to the span element, so the margin will be evaluated based on this measure rather than the text length. The drawback of this solution is that I'm actually putting a constraint on the max text length.

Comment: The `<span>` is centered in the middle probably because the `display: flex` see 3 elements, diplayed by the `<ng-content>` not the 2 `ng-content` them-selves. Try to add a div around the first `ng-content` or around 
`<i icon class="fas fa-2x fa-clipboard-list"></i>
 <span class="span-list-item">{{ item.name }}</span>
`